# django user relationship

Tags: django, model

Using django, say I have model classes A and B, representing different types of Companies.  Each Company may have multiple Users associated with it.  Obviously I'd like to use django's User model, to get the login, etc. goodness.  How would I go about doing that?  Would I add a UserProfile that has two foreign keys, one to A and one to B (and the one that isn't null points to the company that the User works for)?  Or is there another way?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inheritance: define a superclass for Company, with the common fields, and then inherit that class and add the stuff ClassACompany and ClassBCompany need.

This way the UserProfile can have a foreign key to Company. If you need to get from the company to the specific type of company, you can do that as described [in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id7).

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just have one class for Company? that'll make your system much, much simpler.

you can then have specific fields inside Company that will let you determine whether it's of type A or B (what's the difference anyway?)

Comment: Because the different companies have different data, and different relationships - A has multiple Factories, and B has multiple Ships, or whatever.

Comment: then you can break your model down some more. let Company have multiple instances of Asset that has a Type (ship, etc). for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must have different fields inside CompanyA and CompanyB then you can have them both derive from a common Company class which your ForeignKey will point to.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to reference the Company model, and if need be, subclass Company with CompanyA and CompanyB. For simplicity, your Company class could have a `type` attribute with possible `A` and `B` values, then you could avoid subclassing.